# numba не видит аргумент axis в функции numpy.delete

Tags: python, numpy, numba

```
@njit(fastmath=True)
def train():
    ...
    a = np.delete(arr = w1_bias, obj = -1, axis = 0)
    ...
```

Данный код выдает эту ошибку

TypingError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

При этом если убрать @njit(fastmath=True), то всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Почитал [официальную документацию Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#calculation)

При использовании numpy.delete допускается только два первых аргумента.

> numpy.delete() (only the 2 first arguments)

Comment: пишет no such option: -u. Может быть это потому, что у меня питон 3.8.9?

Comment: @rastrey проблема не в этом, сейчас отредактирую ответ